# What does it mean an isolated write operation does not provide “all-or-nothing” atomicity

Tags: mongodb

I am going through transactions using Mongodb and in $isolate operator documentation, it is mentioned

> An isolated write operation does not provide “all-or-nothing”
>   atomicity

in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

It is confusing, then what is the whole purpose of $isolate operator. Can somebody please explain.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$isolated` affects isolation, not atomicity. That is, once the 'isolated' operation modifies the first document a lock is established. From that moment and until the operation is finished and the lock released, any other the client won't see the modifications and other write operations cannot affect the affected documents

For instance, suppose a collection dummy with 3 documents: `{a:1}, {a:3}, {a:5}, {a:6}` and with a unique index on `a`:

```
db.dummy.createIndex({a:1},{unique:true})
```

and the following update:

```
db.dummy.update(
    { $isolated : 1 },
    { $inc : { a : 1 } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

produces:

```
 db.dummy.find({},{_id:0})
{ "a" : 2 }  // 2 --> was 1
{ "a" : 4 }  // 4 --> was 3
{ "a" : 5 }  // 5 --> not changed; produced a duplicated key error
{ "a" : 6 }  // 6 --> not changed; operation aborted before reaching this document
```

The operation has been interrupted when trying to increment 5, because it caused a duplicated key error,and neither 5 nor 6 were affected. There is no atomicity here since the changes in `a:2,a:4` were not rolled back.

What the isolation ensured was that no client could see the collection in this intermediate state:

```
 db.dummy.find({},{_id:0})
{ "a" : 2 }  // 1 --> 2
{ "a" : 3 }  // 3 --> still not modified
{ "a" : 5 }  // 5 --> still not modified
{ "a" : 6 }  // 6 --> still not modified
```

That is, other clients cannot see the operation 'in the middle'; once it has started they will see all the changes together at the end.

A very confusing point here was that `$isolated` was called `$atomic` until version 2.2., this was really confusing but now `$atomic` is deprecated and has been substituted for the more suitable name `$isolated`

Comment: Awesome.Thanks a lot